How many pieces are allowed in checked in baggage for Batik Air?
I have check in baggage allowance of 35 KG. Am I allowed 2 pieces under 35kg or do I have to buy extra baggage?

Batik Air:

For most destinations, your free checked baggage allowance is determined by weight (Weight System).

This means you can take as many bags as you like (within reason), as long as their total weight is less than 35 kg.
See
Can I split my 30kg check-in luggage into multiple suitcases? for a more detailed explanation of the weight vs piece systems.
